# Can't mount SD card that has Raspbian installed on it

Tags: linux, partitioning, raspberry-pi, sd-card, raspbian

I have an 16GB SD card that has Raspbian installed on it.  I reformatted the card to FAT32, then put [NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/) on it, and installed Raspbian on it via my Raspberry Pi.  While the SD card boots just fine, I can't access the filesystem via my computer.  I try to mount the partitions via the command `mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/rasp`, but the command returns an error about specifying the filesystem (and specifying `vfat` as the filesystem doesn't work, either).  What's worse is that the other partitions on the SD card don't show up as `/dev` files.

I have run `fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0`, and it returns the following information:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 15.9 GB, 15931539456 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 486192 cylinders, total 31116288 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00064a26

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1            2048     1683593      840773    e  W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2         1687552    31050751    14681600   85  Linux extended
/dev/mmcblk0p3        31050752    31116287       32768   83  Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p5         1695744     1818623       61440    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p6         1826816    31049727    14611456   83  Linux
```

The thing is, while these partitions are on the SD card, I can't access them via these `/dev` files.  Also, they don't show up as `/dev/sd*` files, either.

If anyone's wondering, here's the output from my syslog:

```
kernel: [   63.410026] mmc1: new ultra high speed SDR50 SDHC card at address aaaa
kernel: [   63.420893] mmcblk0: mmc1:aaaa SU16G 14.8 GiB 
kernel: [   63.434020]  mmcblk0: [CUMANA/ADFS] p1 [ADFS] p1
```

So how can I access the files on the SD card via my computer?

Comment: " Also, they don't show up as /dev/sd* files, either." Just a note, not all drives show up as sd*.

Comment: @MrStatic You're right.  In this case, they can also show up as /dev/mmcblk0p*.  The thing is, those other files don't show up, either. :-/

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/.

If you need a one time access, you can use it for free. It is for Windows.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).